# PSQLException: ERROR: column "attidentity" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, database-metadata, logical-replication

I'm using PostgresSQL 9.6 and have a process that is introspecting the database. I have the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "attidentity" does not exist
  Position: 169
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
```

Do I have to modify my tables? Any guidance?

Comment: What statement is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

Logical replication and replica identity were introduced in PostgreSQL v10, so you won't find that column in the `pg_attribute` catalog in 9.6.